# What is a 'multi-energy band' superconductor?

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity, conductors, quasiparticles

From Phys.org:

They write that in lab experiments they've found a short-lived "Higgs mode" within iron-based, high-temperature (but still very cold), multi-energy band, unconventional superconductors.

Article called, 'Light-controlled Higgs modes found in superconductors; potential sensor, computing uses'.   At Phys.org.

The Higgs modes can be created within different energy bands and still interact with each other.

This just refers to energy levels of the electrons, like we learned in high school chemistry, doesn't it?  Or band-structure levels in elementary solid-state physics....

No wonder nobody is answering or commenting on my dumb question....

More information: C. Vaswani et al, Light quantum control of persisting Higgs modes in iron-based superconductors, Nature Communications (2021). DOI: 10.1038/s41467-020-20350-6

Journal information: Nature Communications

Provided by Iowa State University

Does it have anything to do with the 'continuous' energy bands of a regular conductor?

Or this iron-based superconductor has an exceptionally wide conduction band, even for a superconductor (do they have wider bands than conductors?) that they can fit lots of these interacting Higgs quasiparticle in it?....